# Why the records are not getting pickets for the entry date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have written this query long time ago and it was working but now it's not.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[WeeklyReport]
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #temp
        (
            Area VARCHAR(20),
            NoOfInspec INT
        )

    INSERT INTO #temp
        SELECT DISTINCT
            Area, COUNT(*) AS NoOfInsp 
        FROM 
            EngineeringData E, PIRTaskList T
        WHERE
            E.EnggDataID = t.EnggDataID 
            AND T.NextInspDate BETWEEN (DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
                                   AND (DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
        GROUP BY
            Area

    SELECT
        t.Area, t.NoOfInspec AS Planned, SecTable.NoOfInsp AS Executed 
    FROM
        #temp t
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT
             Area, COUNT(*) AS NoOfInsp  
         FROM
             tblScheduleHistory 
         WHERE
             EntryDate BETWEEN (DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()))
                           AND (DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), GETDATE()))    
        GROUP BY
            Area) SecTable ON SecTable.Area = t.Area
    ORDER BY 
        t.Area
END
```

The `entrydate` dates against the several records are

```
2019-10-06
2019-09-06
2019-11-06
```

The requirement is to select the whole week's records if 1 date is there so whole week for that.

Comment: No need to do SELECT DISTINCT, since your GROUP BY returns no duplicates.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: @CodingManiac . . . "was working" and "not working" are extremely vague and don't provide useful information.

Comment: @jarlh: i removed that but didn't work

Comment: @iamdave I don't agree with adding explicit joins to the OP's code in an edit. It isn't representative of the OP's actual SQL as a result.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that was supposed to be the answer. It was just meant to make you understand SQL better.

Comment: @Larnu Agree, good action ;)

Comment: Here's a thought - people should just STOP EDITING code posted by others just to "beautify" it to their standards.

Comment: CodingManiac, please elaborate why it is 'not working' anymore, as pointed by fellow @GordonLinoff. I and Razvan Socol guessed it could be about SET DATEFIRST, and offered some insights. But, we are just guessing here...

Answer (score 1):

`DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE())` is dependent on the `SET DATEFIRST` option, which is also changed using `SET LANGUAGE`. The default language can also be configured at the server level, using `sp_configure`.

For example, try the following to see the different results:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE='2019-06-16'

SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH
SELECT  DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate), 
        DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate), 
        DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate)
-- returns 1, 2019-06-16, 2019-06-22

SET LANGUAGE BRITISH
SELECT  DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate), 
        DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate), 
        DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate), @CurrentDate)
-- returns 7, 2019-06-10, 2019-06-16
```

To make the code work the same way, regardless of the `SET DATEFIRST` option, you can add `@@DATEFIRST` the following way:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate DATE='2019-06-16'

SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH

SELECT  (@@DATEFIRST-1 + DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate))%7+1,
        DATEADD(DAY, 1 - ((@@DATEFIRST-1 + DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate))%7+1), @CurrentDate), 
        DATEADD(DAY, 7 - ((@@DATEFIRST-1 + DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate))%7+1), @CurrentDate)
-- returns 1, 2019-06-16, 2019-06-22

SET LANGUAGE BRITISH

SELECT  (@@DATEFIRST-1 + DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate))%7+1,
        DATEADD(DAY, 1 - ((@@DATEFIRST-1 + DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate))%7+1), @CurrentDate), 
        DATEADD(DAY, 7 - ((@@DATEFIRST-1 + DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @CurrentDate))%7+1), @CurrentDate)
-- returns 1, 2019-06-16, 2019-06-22
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Razvan Socol for the insight.

I'll try to clarify the crux of the issue as perceived both by Razvab and me.

The code at the end iterates a set of dates outputing the computed lower and upper boundaries within the the date's week.

@Razvan Socol solution may be rewritten as

```
DECLARE @dt date = '20190610'

-- Week starts on sundays
PRINT dateadd(dd, 0 - (datepart(weekday, @dt) + @@datefirst - 1) % 7, @dt)
PRINT dateadd(dd, 6 - (datepart(weekday, @dt) + @@datefirst - 1) % 7, @dt)

-- Week starts on mondays
PRINT dateadd(dd, 0 - (datepart(weekday, @dt) + @@datefirst - 2) % 7, @dt)
PRINT dateadd(dd, 6 - (datepart(weekday, @dt) + @@datefirst - 2) % 7, @dt)
```

Here follows the whole POC.

```
SET DATEFIRST 4

DECLARE @datefirst int = 7 -- 1 weeks start on mondays, 7 weeks start on sundays
DECLARE @dtStart date = '20190605'
DECLARE @dtEnd   date = '20190619'

DECLARE @result table(
    dt varchar(255),
    deltaL int, deltaH int,
    boundaryL varchar(255), boundaryH varchar(255)
)

DECLARE @deltaL    int,  @deltaH     int
DECLARE @boundaryL date, @boundaryH  date

WHILE @dtStart <= @dtEnd
BEGIN
    -- Computes DATEPART as ISO 8601, where Monday == 1,
    -- adjusting to @dateFirst
    DECLARE @iso8601 int =
        (
            datepart(weekday, @dtStart) - /* shifted to base 0 */ 1 + 
            @@datefirst                 - /* shifted to base 0 */ 1 +
            --
            (7 - @datefirst + 1) -- Shifted for @datefirst
        ) % 7 + 1

    SET @deltaL = 1 - @iso8601
    SET @deltaH = 7 - @iso8601
    --
    SET @boundaryL = dateadd(dd, @deltaL, @dtStart)
    SET @boundaryH = dateadd(dd, @deltaH, @dtStart)

    INSERT INTO @result
    VALUES(
        convert(varchar, @dtStart, 120) + ' ' + datename(weekday, @dtStart),
        @deltaL, @deltaH,
        convert(varchar, @boundaryL, 120) + ' ' + datename(weekday, @boundaryL),
        convert(varchar, @boundaryH, 120) + ' ' + datename(weekday, @boundaryH)
    )

    SET @dtStart = dateadd(dd, 1, @dtStart)
END

SELECT * FROM @result
```